# Modifying SMPS power supply to produce a negative voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, negative-voltage, tl431

In SMPS power supply that uses a single transistor to generate the switching signal ( no control IC), which component must be modified so the output voltage could be **negative**?

I tried to reverse the polarity of the output shotkey diode and I connected a 100w lamp in series with the line for protection,after a few seconds the lamp turns on, and the MOSFET got so hot.

[image],

Comment: As that's an isolated supply, this is very easy. Cross out "+" and write in GND. The other terminal is now -12V. In other words the component you need to modify is the **label**.

Comment: As others have noted:  The output provides +ve **AND** -ve on the same half cycle. Changing the diode to the other leg makes NO difference and changing its polarity changes to the wrong part of the flyback cycle. Leaving it as is and grounding the current positive output and using the current negative as -Vout is all that is required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how flyback circuits work. Just reversing the diode doesn't help. That blocks power transfer.

Power is transferred during the switch off time.

You need to put the rectifier diode at the other end of the secondary (the finish) in reverse orientation (same direction of current flow as at present). Then it'll work.

But why ? The output is isolated anyway. You decide what is negative and what is positive. Just reverse the output terminals !

Comment: There is no 'alternate half cycle' in a flyback converter of course.

Comment: Of course BF....

Comment: Sorry - this is incorrect - You've fallen into a trap. It's easy enough. The output provides +ve OR -ve on the same half cycle. Changing the diode to the other leg makes NO difference and changing its polarity changes to the wrong part of the flyback cycle. Leaving it as is and grounding the current positive output and using the current negative as -Vout is all that is required (as others have noted).

Comment: Pardon ? The stored energy in the core is transferred during the 'flyback period'. In my suggestion, I moved the diode to the other leg AND reversed it, thus maintaining conduction during that part of the cycle.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson I think you are missing the point here.

Comment: I think 'the point' left the building a long time ago. Just connect the output the other way round !

Comment: Thank you all for helping.

Actually, I tried to move the diode to another side with and without reverse it, but it stays the same problem.
I just grounded the positive and take the negative voltage from -V and it's work just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

100W lamp draws 1kW on startup  *if shorted load*. 

<s>Don’t test with that unless you use PWM switch for soft start on load.</s>
Your temp rise is limited by efficiency and thermal resistance.
Recheck you assumptions.

<s>Otherwise  use</s> Consider a much lower RdsOn than 0.85 Ohm *or better heatsink.*

Polarity on isolated output is your choice. No problem here.

I suspect your switching frequency is too low and output cap too big.  Compute the Bode plot for each RLC and choose a trade off to allow BW of loop to regulate the output rather than brute force output cap.

dV/dt = Ic/C
Reversing the output diode should block the load and reflect all the stored inductive energy back into the driver. V^2/RdsOn * t

Comment: The OP isn't using the 100W lamp as the load. It's wired in series with the input line as a crude 'protection' and overcurrent 'problem' indicator.

Comment: OK Thanks @brhans